# Boruto's Right Eye

Tags: naruto, boruto

So, I have watched the first 3 episodes of Boruto already, and they seem interesting so far. But being a person who watched the Boruto movie first, I have a lot of questions in my mind. One of them is about Boruto's right eye. Whenever he unintentionally activated his right eye, he is able to see chakra, just like the Byakugan, except it can't see complex chakra flows.

[image]

So, it looks very much like the Byakugan, except the eye turns black, and there is no veins or whatever at the side of his face.
[image]

So is this really the Byakugan, if it is, what type of Byakugan is this? Is it because of Boruto's mother? In general, what kind of Kekkei Genkai is Boruto's right eye?

Comment: It just looks eye like the after using the Izanami, just like in the fight of Itachi ( Ido tensei form ) and Kabuto

Comment: [It is now known](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/55789/1604).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The nature of Boruto's eye is currently unknown.**

However we can speculate. First we need to understand that both of Naruto's kids are unique in the sense Hyuga have traditionally preserved their bloodline by marrying within the branch family. Naruto is probably the first outsider who has married into the main branch.

This gets further complicated by the fact Naruto is the reincarnation of the Asura, son of the Sage of Six paths and inherited the Sage's life energy.

Thus probable options are

- Byakugan: It is a normal Byakugan but not fully awakened or controlled because of the mixing of bloodlines.
- Tenseigan: In Naruto: The Last we learnt about Tenseigan, which is equivalent to Byakugan, in the same way Rinnegan is to Sharingan.

However, what I would put my money on is 
- An Unknown Third eye: Sharingan has Mangekyou capabilities. Kishimoto didn't get a chance to explore Byakugan that much because it was not the focus. The new author now has the creative license under Kishimoto to explore the limits and capabilities of Byakugan and how it can evolve.

Comment: It is plausible...

Comment: swagkage speculates the same in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bko7zRmtum0&t=4s

Comment: Interesting video. But Boruto is still in a nascent stage and we can pretty much speculate anything.

Comment: the nature is now known , it is dojutsu

Comment: @Shashi456 The literal meaning of Dojutsu is "Eye Techniques"... Obviously Bouto's eye technique. by definition a Dojutsu.... What we don't know it how it relates to Byakugan and how mixing of Hyuga and Uzumaki Chakra affect it

Comment: There's a more direct relation to momoshiki's power . It could be said that the power directly comes from as a result of the seal on borutos palm

Answer (score 2):

I think that Boruto's eye is a cross-section between the Byakugan and the Tenseigan as he has both Hamura's and Hagoromo's chakra.

Comment: this is speculation at best, and is practically a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: But how, then...

Answer (score 2):

This is only a theory. Much like the Mangekyo Sharingan, I believe that the Tenseigan has other forms. I do think that it could also be a minor version of the Tenseigan or like most people say, a cross between a Byakugan and a Tenseigan.

[image]

Comment: Could be possible

Answer (score 1):

We now have the information regarding Boruto's right eye. It is called the [Jōgan](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/J%C5%8Dgan) which translates to **Pure Eye**.

As per the [anime's wiki page](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/J%C5%8Dgan) (emphasis mine)

> **The Jōgan is a unique dōjutsu that is known to the Ōtsutsuki Clan, whose members claim it's troublesome and that it's a power strongly inherited from their clan.**
>
> In the manga the dōjutsu is featureless in appearance with a barely visible pupil. When depicted in the anime, the dōjutsu is blue in colour with a darkened sclera and visible pupil.
>
> **When first used during his time in the Academy, Boruto did not appear to have the ability to activate it on command; instead, the eye would involuntarily activate when Boruto focused his attention on a particular person or object. As a teenager, he displayed the ability to activate it at will.**

---

Now, coming to the actual questions posted by OP.

1. So is this really the Byakugan, if it is, what type of Byakugan is this?

   > No, it is not Byakugan or related to the Byakugan.

   As per the trivia in the anime wiki page (emphasis mine)

   > Chengxi Huang, who is an animator for Boruto: Naruto Next Generations, posted a picture on his blog that shows Boruto cleaning his right eye. The caption of the picture reads "Jōgan" (浄眼, Literally meaning: Pure Eye) and in the accompanying text, **the animator elaborated that Boruto's eye was neither a Byakugan nor a Tenseigan.** He also explained that the eye is related to the Ōtsutsuki clan's dimension and its powers are the dōjutsu equivalent of Naruto's ability to sense negative emotions. **However, he then noted that all this information would be explained in detail in the future and fans should not think too much of it for now, as the author hadn't thought everything through himself.**
2. Is it because of Boruto's mother?

   > Since it is not related to the Byakugan, it is most likely not related to Hinata either.
3. In general, what kind of Kekkei Genkai is Boruto's right eye?

   > It is a [Dōjutsu](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/D%C5%8Djutsu).

Answer (score 0):

Boruto's eye is a Jougan. It's a mix of Hagoromo and Haruma chakra, so it has an effect greater than the Sharingan and the Byakugan. The Jougan can see evil chakra and good chakra. It powers up the person's speed, strength, reflexes, etc.