# What is the lightning coming out from Boruto's eye at the end of 13th episode of Boruto?

Tags: naruto, boruto

Is this some power used by him unknowingly?

Comment: [Related](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/39979/borutos-right-eye)

Comment: related, but not giving the answer of my question, may be it is not expected from that question. I am asking about specific event.

Comment: maybe it was the chakra being drained from him?! we see that the lightning that comes out of his eye goes to class rep and then the monster gets bigger and is able toteleport. maybe the chakra gained from the eye made it whole?!

Answer (score 2):

It is Dojutsu, the ability to detect things such as chakra which is generally unseen by a normal eye. At the age of 8, which is the age he is at currently within the anime, he is able to use it subconsciously, i.e. unknowingly but at the right moments. But if you watch the first episode where we see a teenage Boruto we see that Boruto is now able to use the Dojutsu, i.e. his eye on his own will.

The origins of this power are still unknown, and I can only speculate that this is somehow related to the seal that Momoshiki presents on Boruto's palm after Boruto defeats him.

Comment: Pretty sure the anime has not reached that point even yet. It started with Boruto starting at the Academy, which is long before the Chunin exams when he beat Momoshiki. So in Anime canon, the seal does not exist yet. Also, its noted the seal was given right after saying a cryptic warning that someone who defeats a god ceases to be a normal person.

Comment: @Ryan that is something that eludes me, because in the manga the dojutsu is an extension of his seal. The power was not experienced before it .